# Javascript function in constructor not working for onclick

Tags: javascript, constructor, onclick

I'm trying to run a function called makeHighlight within my constructor SmartButton.  makeHighlight is supposed to run whenever I click on the SmartButton object (an image element) which is why I set the attribute 'onclick' to makeHighlight.  I can't get it to work, it either doesn't run at all or runs instantaneously when the page loads.

```
function SmartButton(buttonId, defaultImage, highlightImage, helpMsg) {
    var newLink = document.createElement('a');
        newLink.setAttribute('href', '#');

    var newImg = document.createElement('img');
        newImg.setAttribute('src', defaultImage);
        newImg.setAttribute('id', buttonId);
        newImg.setAttribute('onclick', "makeHighlight()");

    document.body.appendChild(newLink);
    newLink.appendChild(newImg);

    this.buttonId = buttonId;
    this.defaultImage = defaultImage;
    this.highlightImage = highlightImage;
    this.helpMsg = helpMsg;

    function makeHighlight() {
        newImg.setAttribute('src', highlightImage);
        console.log(this);
    }

}   

button1 = new SmartButton('button1', 'button1off.jpg', 'button1on.jpg', 'sup');
```

Comment: @jcolebrand It does not, because of the event bubbling. If he specifies the `href`, then it will take him to the other page, but JavaScript will still fire (although he won't see the effect obviously :) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `makeHighlight` in the scope of `SmartButton` function. Thus `newImg` when clicked does not see it. Try this code (inside `SmartButton`):

```
function makeHighlight() {
    newImg.setAttribute('src', highlightImage);
    console.log(this);
}
newImg.onclick = makeHighlight;
```

(note the lack of brackets in the last line) and remove this line:

```
newImg.setAttribute('onclick', "makeHighlight()");
```

Comment: Wow that worked.  Was it because I set the onclick attribute to the function before I defined the function?

Comment: @yeenow123 No, this is because `makeHighlight` **is not** a global function. And when you set attribute (like you did) JavaScript looks for a function in global scope. You need to learn a lot about JavaScript, young padawan! :)